# Clarify some things from the song by Elton Britt - Uranium Fever

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I need your help with the song by [Elton Britt - Uranium Fever](https://genius.com/Elton-britt-uranium-fever-lyrics)

I don't understand some things in this song.

1. What does "sold my cad" mean?

> Well, I don't know, but I've been told
> Uranium ore's worth more than gold
> **Sold my Cad'**, I bought me a Jeep
> I've got that bug and I can't sleep

2. The phrase "Has done and got me down"

> Uranium fever **has done and got me down**
> Uranium fever is spreadin' all around

3. "That bug's done caught me and I've been bit"

> Well, I ain't kiddin', I ain't gonna quit
> **That bug's done caught me and I've been bit**
> So with a Geiger counter and a pick in my hand
> I'll keep right on stakin' that government land

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The apostrophe after the Cad is a big hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In "sold my Cad'", *Cad'* is short for [Cadillac](http://www.cadillac.com/), a (luxury) brand of automobile.

2) The various structures that include an extra "done" are indicative of an American South or Midwest *dialect*.  For example:

> I **done been** told -> I was told
>
> I **done** and got me a new tractor -> I got a new tractor
>
> It **done** rained on her parade -> It [rained on her parade](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rain-on-sb-s-parade)

If something has "got you down" it means it has made you sad, upset, frustrated, or depressed.

> The constant stream of bad news has really **got me down**.

3) "That bug's caught me and I've been bit".  A "bug" can mean a bacteria or virus that causes disease, so "to catch a bug" means "to get sick".

> Some **bug** is going around.  All my friends **caught** it and are at home sick.

Since "bug" can also mean "insect", and insects can bite, idiomatically when you get a disease we can say you have been "bit" by some "bug".  In this case the "bug" isn't a physical illness but rather an obsessive desire to get rich by finding uranium, i.e. "Uranium Fever".

Note that a "fever" can be a physical symptom of illness marked by elevated body temperature, but also, to be *hot* for something, or to have a *fever* for something *figuratively* means to be particularly excited about it, as if it makes you feel *feverish*.

Comment: "done been" is also used in the US South.   *I done been drug along*.

Comment: I learned many interesting from this. Thank you very much, Andrew, for such an extensive answer!